# firestore: cannot connect from xamarin forms (Bad gRPC response)

Tags: c#, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, xamarin.forms

I am trying to create data on the backend using this code:

```
  var db = FirestoreDb.Create("interiorcircle");

                DocumentReference docRef = db.Collection("users").Document("alovelace");
                Dictionary<string, object> user = new Dictionary<string, object>
                {
                    { "First", "Ada" },
                    { "Last", "Lovelace" },
                    { "Born", 1815 }
                };
                await docRef.SetAsync(user);
```

This is from the official docs here:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart?authuser=0

I set up the envoirment variable and i am able to connect, but the http connection when calling "setAsync" fails with:

```
Bad gRPC response. Response protocol downgraded to HTTP/1.1.
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: what is your Grpc.Net.Client version?

Comment: is this a library I need to install? I dont think I ever did anything like this... Where would I find that? I dont see it under dependencies...

Comment: can you see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66258950/15774176) is it helpful?

Comment: it states that I have to also adjust settings on server side. Is this true? I will try client side now

Comment: Also it doesnt seem to help me, as it is about asp.net and it doesnt translate to well to xamarin.forms

Comment: can you briefly explain your issue once, that might helpful in troubleshooting.

Comment: my issue is that I am simply trying to follow to the docs and sending a create request to the firestore DB. but when I try to send the request, my xamarin.forms application fails with the above error. I tried everything, installing all libraries I could find but wasnt able to get any other error message then the one above.

Comment: can you refer to this [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#c) is it helpful?